# How to include ui.bootstrap.datepicker into ng-boilerplate

Tags: datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap, ngboilerplate

I am currently using ngboilerplate from: https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp

I want to include the 'ui.bootstrap.datepicker' from UI-Bootstrap (Twitter Bootstrap written natively in AngularJS). The problem is that this doesn't seem to be included in the latest version of ngboilerplate. Does anyone know how I can add this accordingly to the style of ngboilerplate.

This means that other developers can load it as a dependency with bower install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a couple of things it seems to be quite easy actually. I'll just answer this question in case someone else has the same problem.

I needed to install a new version of UI-Bootstrap. This can be done with bower by executing (on windows):

bower install angular-bootstrap

But this will give you a whole lot of other problems with dependencies.

To resolve this I use this bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "Your-app",
  "version": "0.3.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.4",
    "angular-mocks": "1.2.4",
    "bootstrap": "3.0.3",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.10.0",
    "angular-ui-utils": "0.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-ui-router": "0.2.8-bowratic-tedium"
  },
  "resolutions": {
  }
}
```

Another problem I had was that the LESS code for bootstrap isn't up to date. Instead I just included the bootstrap.css in my main.less file.

Comment: just add the line into bower.json and run **bower install**